# Forbidden (error 403) while sending request to Twitter API

Tags: c#, api, twitter

I want to get a Tweets list using GET statuses/**home_timeline**. My Resource URL without any additional parameters. When I send a request, I get the error Forbidden. A part of of code below

```
  public async Task<BindableCollection<Tweet>> Execute()
    {
        string uri = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "api.twitter.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", info.TokenType + ' ' + info.AccessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage responce = new HttpResponseMessage();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                responce = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                break;
            }
            catch { Debug.WriteLine("ERROR!"); }
        }
```

`info.TokenType` and `info.AccessToken` contain "bearer" and my access token 
in accordance.
[Appropriate photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPqpP.jpg)

When I sent the request (GET statuses / **USER_timeline**) with this parameters (TokenType and AccessToken)I got the correct answer.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to differentiate HomeTimeline and UserTimeline.

- HomeTimeline is the timeline of the currently authenticated user, so you must have a user specific authentication.
- UserTimeline is the public timeline of a specific user, you can use Application-Only authentication.

Tweetinvi gives a very straight access to both of these :

```
var tweets = Timeline.GetHomeTimeline();
// OR
var tweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(<user_identifier>);
```

[Timeline documentation](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Timelines)

For authentication you will also need 1 line:

```
// User authentication
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
// Application-Only authentication
Auth.SetApplicationOnlyCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", true);
```

[Authentication documentation](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Credentials)

Let me know if this is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

HOME_timeline requires user authentication as opposed to application authentication, which can be used with User_timeline. Are you authenticated using application credentials perchance?

From [the docs](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only):

"With Application-only authentication you don’t have the context of an authenticated user and this means that any request to API for endpoints that require user context, such as posting tweets, will not work. However, the set of endpoints that will still be available can have a higher rate limit."

Answer (score 1):

As Ian Nelson said you need an authorization to access to your timeline. But you can use [LinqToTwitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) for getting a list of tweets.

```
 var tweets = from tweet in twitterContext.Status
                where tweet.Type == StatusType.User
                      && tweet.ScreenName == "Goofy"
                select tweet;
```

Comment: So I can't get `home_timeline` using Application-only authentication in my app. But I want to get home_timeline, how I can do this?

Comment: @MAXIMAN you can download the demos and there's documentation in the Wiki. Try SingleUserAuthorizer and get AccessToken/AccessTokenSecret from your Twitter app page: https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter